# pyramid AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy with other frameworks

Tags: python, authentication, twisted, comet, pyramid

I need to use the authentication cookie that AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy from pyramid authorizes with a Twisted server so I can do long polling efficiently. Is there a way to allow the Twisted server to decode the authentication cookie from pyramid?

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` code follows a standard set my the `mod_tkt_auth` Apache module. If you implement the same algorithm and configure it on your Twisted server to use the same secret as used by your Pyramid server, you can decode that cookie, yes.

In fact, Pyramid re-used the `tkt_auth` code from the Paste project to accomplish this, licensed under the very permissive MIT license. You could probably reuse it for your Twisted application too; find it at [the Paste bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/ianb/paste/src/tip/paste/auth/auth_tkt.py).

The `parse_ticket()` function just needs the server-side secret, the cookie value, the ip address of the remote connection and optionally the hash algorithm used (MD5 is the default).